# How do I uncheck a Toolbar button in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I have created a toolbar having 6 button to add/turn on different layers.

I want to have a functionality in my toolbar buttons, by which it will enable the user to see which layer is being added/turned on. Basically to turn the "checked" value as True.

Please see my code below.

```
class DG(object):
    """Implementation for DG_Imagery_addin.DG (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False

    def onClick(self):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
            if lyr.longName in lyrlst:
                lyr.visible = False

        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
            if lyr.longName == "MapProxy WMS\MapProxy WMS\DG":
                ispresnt = True
                islyr = lyr
                break
            else:
                ispresnt = False
        if ispresnt == True:
            islyr.visible = True
        else:
            df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
            imagery_lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"D:\Layer_Don'tDelete\DG.lyr")
            arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, imagery_lyr)
        arcpy.RefreshTOC()
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

class DG_CLEAR(object):
    """Implementation for DG_Imagery_addin.DG_CLEAR (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
            if lyr.longName in lyrlst:
                lyr.visible = False

        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
            if lyr.longName == "MapProxy WMS\MapProxy WMS\DG_CLEAR":
                ispresnt = True
                islyr = lyr
                break
            else:
                ispresnt = False
        if ispresnt == True:
            islyr.visible = True
        else:
            df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
            imagery_lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"D:\Layer_Don'tDelete\DG_CLEAR.lyr")
            arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, imagery_lyr)
        arcpy.RefreshTOC()
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

And 4 more buttons like this.

Now after clicking a button, how could I uncheck rest of the buttons and check my current button only.

Comment: Many UI implementations use the concept of a "Button Group", where each member of the group messages the group object when it is checked, so that the group can uncheck the other members.  This is more a software engineering issue than a GIS one, however, since the question is more of how to implement a button group than how to uncheck a button.

Comment: So how would I enable this?

Comment: Add a registerGroup method, and create a Group class that allows adding a list of buttons and accepts a radio request. Then add a conditional radio request when the button is toggled to True.

Comment: @Vince I have a little knowledge in what you are saying, however I think this answer could solve this issue. Turning off button during runtime. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/64949/140271